# Adding Material/Texture on Sculpt does not work?

Tags: texturing, materials, shader-nodes

I tried adding material/texture to my mesh for the first time, and while it works just fine on geometric objects like a basic Sphere, it does not work on my sculpt.

To prove my point, I tried adding tree bark as a material on my sculpted figure - strangly, only the eyeballs (which were seperated UV spheres before but I did join them with the whole body) seem to accept the material, the rest of the body just dyes browny without gaining any texture at all.
This is the case with a couple of objects inside my project, and I can't put my finger on the reason.

[image]

[image]

What step did I miss? Did I make a grave mistake? I tried finding videos on this problem but without success.. So I would be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not using mapping nodes and the UV of your model is not unwrapped, for example, sphere works because it has default UV that works with your texture, but your body sculpt doesn't have a UV map or UV map is distorted by sculpting, try to add these two nodes:
[image]

Before your texture, does Generated or Object option work? Then you need to fix your UV before applying texture to it and change it to UV input in texture coordinate...

If I don't use mapping:
[image]

If I use mapping:
[image]

After UV unwrap with Sphere projection:
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! This saves me a lot of stress :)

Comment: Oh and btw don't forget to apply scale before unwrapping, Ctrl+A and select Scale before unwrapping

Comment: Done, I appreciate it!!